# What's the correct way to include both GTM and gtag scripts?

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I'm using both gtag as well as GTM; how do I correctly include both of them in the ? Also, I was wondering if I should be overriding the dataLayer variable or checking if it already exists on every page -- i.e. `dataLayer = [];` or `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];`?

Does this look correct?

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
</script>

<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UAXXXX"></script>

<script>
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fully answers your concern: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7582054?hl=en

In short: remove your gtag completely and have all your tracking logic within GTM.

A tag manager is meant to house all your analytics logic and be the single point of access to anything behavioral tracking-related.

Regarding your DL question,

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

is more adequate. Never redefine/overwrite the DL. Even when you believe it's not there. Async can be vicious, so be safe is always good in this case.

Oh, also GTM provides dataLayer automatically, so if you're moving your logic to it, you can as well skip defining it to leave the source cleaner. Or you can define it on the template level in case you want to be able to push into it before GTM is loaded.

Comment: It's a business requirement that we use both GTM and gtag. We need to customize and make API calls to gtag to get the clientID, but we don't want to lose the ability to manage _other_ tags with GTM. What now?

Comment: I don't think business is ever qualified enough to require a js library. Or any library really. It's very likely that all that customisation is doable through GTM.

Comment: Apparently either GA4 or retrieving the generated clientId is not doable via GTM. Gtag has an API for getting values; GTM does not.

Comment: GTM doesn't have the built-in thing for this, but you can always talk to gtag through GTM. Also, GTM is perfectly capable of getting cookies and your clientid is nothing but a cookie.